# What SVG tags are required for Xcode & Swift Support?

Tags: swift, xcode, bash, svg

I am attempting to write a Swift Package for [Iconoir, located here](https://github.com/iconoir-icons/iconoir). I have written a bash script that downloads all of the SVG's to a local folder.

```
for svg_url in ${icon_list}; do
    icon_file=$(basename "${svg_url}")
    icon_name="${icon_file%.*}"
    local_icon_path="${ASSETS_DIR}/${icon_name}.imageset"
    
    if [[ ! -f "${local_icon_path}/${icon_name}.pdf" ]]; then
        mkdir -p "${local_icon_path}"
        
        # Download the SVG file
        curl -sL -o "${local_icon_path}/${icon_file}" "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iconoir-icons/iconoir/${svg_url}"
```

Which does work as expected. The thing that I've noticed is that all of the `.svg` files, while they are valid and can be opened in any SVG viewer, are not supported in Xcode. I can add them, using this same script, into an `.imageset` and they show as valid in Xcode, but are invisible. Both the `SVG` and `Contents.json` are in the same directory and it matches exactly as if you had manually added a file to the project w/ references.

```
        # Create JSON file for the icon in Assets.xcassets
        json_file="${local_icon_path}/Contents.json"
        cat <<-JSON > "${json_file}"
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "filename" : "${icon_name}.pdf",
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "scale" : "3x"
    }
  ],
    "info" : {
        "author" : "xcode",
        "version" : 1
    }
}
JSON
```

I have tried manually downloading the images and adding them by hand, for sanity, and even when doing that it still does not show up. I have toyed around with setting `Scales` and other image set options, but nothing seems to work. My final attempt was to use `cairosvg` to convert them to a PDF thinking that would fix it, but I can't seem to get that dependency to work on my machine despite my best efforts.

```
# Convert the SVG file to a PDF file
/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/cairosvg "${local_icon_path}/${icon_file}" -o "${local_icon_path}/${icon_name}.pdf"
```

Cairo throws all sorts of errors with finding the expected dependency libraries and ultimately I gave up with it. In short, I want to automate the downloading of these SVG's and add them to the `Media.xcassets` folder in my Xcode project. The SVG's are not formatted properly, and I don't know why. What format is required, and is there a way I can modify each SVG to confirm it will work, before adding it to the project?

[Click Here for Script GIST](https://gist.github.com/mkaulfers/2200dcfa76bad800823eca0e975103f6)

Comment: How are you using the svg file in your swift code? I manually downloaded and added an icon and it shows up in my UI.

Comment: Are you able to actually have it appear by doing `Image("some-svg-name")` ? Which icon did you use by chance?

Comment: Actually, just tested again, using the 1st-medal.svg, in a separate xcode on a separate machine, still the same effect, can't be used.

Comment: The last one I tried was "two-points-circle" and "1st-medal.svg" works fine for me. Have you tried downloading manually from https://iconoir.com and check if it works?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson interesting, downloading from the website works just fine. Seems it only happens when you download them via https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iconoir-icons/iconoir/main/icons/1st-medal.svg There must be some processing happening to it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson found a solution if you're curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the icons in `Iconoir.com` were missing the following properties on their main `<svg></svg?` tag.

##### Original Value

```xml
stroke="currentColor"
```

##### Corrected Value

```xml
stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1"
```

Xcode would not recognize an SVG without having a stroke-width and also a stroke color. The initial `currentColor` was intended for use to make it dynamic with the web portion if Iconoir, not the iOS version.

Comment: The same occurs for Iconic.app icons. I found that when you open your svg file in Inkscape and save as optimised svg then it properly writes stroke value (actual value not currentColor). So if you have complex svg with multiple paths it can be easier to save it like this instead of manually editing svg.